# how to logout a dropbox account with php

Tags: php, dropbox-php

i am using dropbox php SDK and  i want to know is there any way to logged out the dropbox account with any php function???

i am using this code using curl to logged out

```
function logout() 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url="https://www.dropbox.com/logout";

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    // grab URL and pass it to the browser
    curl_exec($ch);
    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: You mean a client side logout? Then call this client side in a hidden iframe. Serverside? What is your goal?

Comment: i want to logged out from server side.i.e i just wan that user will logged out from dropbox.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be achieved server side, as long there is no api existing.

Try this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.dropbox.com/logout" style="display:hidden" />
```

---

**If your problem is OAuth related:**

This would be related to the part of your application, where you check, if you need an OAuth Request. Simple require new Authentification there.

*For example:* simple remove your Token from persistence